# What does the URL parameter in Netty's WebSocketServerHandshaker class do?

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I'm writing a websocket server in Java using the Netty library (version 4.0). When a client connects, there's a websocket handshake that has to be done. I'm using Netty's `WebSocketServerHandshaker` class to do this, and creating the instances of this class through an instance of `WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory`. In the constructor of the factory, the first parameter is a URL.

I don't understand the purpose of this parameter: the client tells the server what URL they want to use, so why is there a URL parameter in the server handshaker? Looking through Netty's source code, I couldn't find where this parameter was actually used, and Netty's documentation isn't much help on the matter either. Furthermore, changing the value of the parameter doesn't seem to affect the operation of my program (which seems to be running fine).

So, does this parameter do anything? And if so, what should I be setting it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, it's used [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketServerHandshaker00.java#L134) for setting **Sec-WebSocket-Location** header:

```
res.headers().add(SEC_WEBSOCKET_LOCATION, uri());
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked at several of the WebSocketServerHandshakerXX.java files, but not WebSocketServerHandshaker00.java, and that's the only one the uses the URL parameter. It seems that this is a security feature in version 00 of the protocol that has been eliminated in subsequent versions. All the browsers I've tested use version 13 of the protocol, which is why this parameter is irrelevant to them.